# Create a Slack channel list on spreadsheets that updates every minutes or so

Tags: javascript, python, excel, spreadsheet, slack

Could someone tell me a way to make a Slack channel list on spread sheet like google or excel that automatically updates every minutes or so?

In detail, I want to have a spread sheet where there is a list of every channel from my Slack (the number of channel are frequently changing as we create channel for each project we get for our work and delete on that is no longer in use).

Please let me know if you have a solution and if I was not clear enough, do ask me!

Comment: Have you checked on here for any q&a that download from websites?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

From API perspective, you can use https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list

This API when used with proper scopes will give you the details of all the channels belonging to a given Team/Workspace.

You can now code as per your skill set to make a call to this API periodically.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering!! But I'm so new to this that I did not quite understand how this goes. If there are any tutorial of this, please kindly share! It would be super helpful!